# how to auto update file path in file header with autocmd in vi/vim?

Tags: vim, path, vi, autocmd

I have a function in my .vimrc that automatically updates the file I'm currently editing with the timestamp (Modified) of the last 'save' (:w).

I would like to also update the Filename and Filepath. I have an autocmd that updates the filename (through expand("%"). As for the Filepath, from what I read in the documentation, using expand("%:p:h") should permit me to insert the path (excluding the filename), but it does not work.

Anybody can tell me how insert the Filepath in my header ?

Example of file header that I wish to update:

```
Modified: November 13 2016
Filename: myfile
Filepath: /home/me/path/tomyfile/
```

Code I have at the moment :

```
autocmd BufWritePre * call UpdHeader()

function! UpdHeader()   
  " update path <<<<<<  DOES NOT WORK  >>>>>>>
  silent! execute "1," . 10 .  "g/Filepath:.*/s//Filepath: " .expand("%:p:h")

  " update filename  <<WORKS>>
  silent! execute "1," . 10 .  "g/Filename:.*/s//Filename: " . expand("%")

  " update last mod date <<WORKS>>
  silent! execute "1," . 10 .  "g/Modified:.*/s//Modified: " . strftime("%d %B %Y%t%t%T (%z)%tBy : ") . $USER
  ...
endf
```

thx!
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform proper escaping on the filepath, as you use `/` both as a separator in `:substitute`, and the (Unix-style) replacement path also has `/` separators in it. `:substitute` would have alerted your via `E488: Trailing characters`, but you've `:silent!` it.

A quick fix would be switching of `:substitute` separators, hoping that `#` will never appear in a file path:

```
silent! execute "1," . 10 .  "g/Filepath:.*/s##Filepath: " .expand("%:p:h")
```

Better do proper escaping:

```
silent! execute "1," . 10 .  "g/Filepath:.*/s//Filepath: " .escape(expand("%:p:h"), '/\'. (&magic ? '&~' : ''))
```

Alternatively, you can replace with an expression:

```
silent! execute "1," . 10 .  "g/Filepath:.*/s//\\='Filepath: ' .expand('%:p:h')"
```

Your filename expansion would benefit from that as well.

Comment: Thank you Ingo, all 3 of your proposed solutions work as expected :). I will be using the 2nd one, seems the best with proper escaping.

(will also similarily modify the Filename expansion as well)

Comment: Oh and Ingo, can you explain the '(&magic ? '&~' : ''))' part please?

Comment: The escaping of the replacement part depends on the `'magic'` setting; usually, it's on, so `&` and `~` must be escaped, too.